# How to integrate ratchet with zend framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, ratchet

I have a web application built with ZF2, now  I would like to integrate ratchet library with my app for a real time notification functionality.

Can anyone help me out with this? I really dont have any idea where to start and how the listening to another port idea of ratchet has to be implemented or do I have to keep ratchet as a seperate app? If so, how can I use to communicate with my app?

Comment: Setup ratchet as the documentation shows, then you can use something such as ZMQ (Zero Message Queue) to communicate between web requests and the websocket process. Using supervisor to manage the websocket process works well also. This is all I got for this at the moment but could add details on request later.